# How can I import a directive in my vue app without using CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am struggling to add a vue directive to my app that detects clicks outside of an element.

I installed it with npm and imported it in my scripttag like this:

```
import clickOutside from './node_modules/vue-detect-click-outside/index.js';
```

I then use it like this:

```
let app = Vue.createApp({
    // Data to work with
    data: function(){
        return{
            // Object to fill with JSON response
            results:[],
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", this.nextItem);
    },
    // Methods contains function that fire upon the (computed) data
    methods:{
        clickedOutside() {
            console.log("clicked outside");
        }
    }
})

app.mount('#v_search');
```

But I get: Failed to resolve directive: click-outside

I added the function on a button to test like this:

```
<button type="submit" @click.prevent="fetchResults" class="searchButton" v-click-outside="{
handler: 'clickedOutside',
exclude: ['excluded']
}">
```

What am I doing wrong? I didn’t use the CLI or anything to start a project. I built my project in jquery first and am now trying to convert it to Vue.

Comment: "imported it in my scripttag like this" - where? "I then use it like this" - you don't use clickOutside anywhere. You could likely specify it in `directives` option.  It's unclear what you exactly do. By CLI do you mean Vue CLI? If you try to do this with `<script>` and no build process, you will naturally have problems. A lot of third-party Vue libs don't support that. Even if you'll be able to make vue-detect-click-outside work, the next lib will fail

Comment: from the code you gave it looks like you just imported it. that doesn't always mean it's going to be used just because you imported it. you have to register it. Docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html